# How can I tell whether a folder has been set up in Git?

Tags: windows, git, cmd, windows-10

I'm confused. The following commands were executed on a Windows 10 command window:

[image: commands that confuse me]

First I list all the .git files on the entire C drive, then go to a specific directory where none was found and enter "git status". That command returns status, indicating that that directory (or a parent of it) HAS been initialized as a local git repository. For good measure, I list all the files found in that directory as well.

How can that directory return git status if neither it nor its ancestors have ".git" files in them?

A history -- I am fairly sure that I executed "git init" in this directory, but I have now changed my mind and want to get rid of its status as a git repository. I thought that would be done by deleting the ".git" file, hence my search (for the file and for information). Is there some other way to remove the 'git' status of a directory?

Comment: Please don't post text as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows `.git` folder is hidden by default and `dir` command doesn't show hidden files by default.

Running `dir /A` should list missing `.git` folder.

Comment: poop. thanks, should have thought of that. Shows files/directories starting with ".", but has its own hidden flag.